# Unsure Of How To New-Line Each String Inside An Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, newline

This was for my assignment, which I've handed in and already been graded on and passed. I guess this step wasn't necessary but in the sample my professor had it so I assumed we had to do it as well.

The problem was simple. Prompt the user to enter 5 student names, and then use an array to list the names in alphabetical order.

In the sample, they had the sorted student names on each new line. So:

Abby
Emma
Hannah
Jake
Zeek

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2> Assignment 1 - Task 4: 5 Student List </h2>

<p id="task 4"></p>

<script>

var Student1 = prompt("Enter the student's name");
document.write(" Student 1: " + Student1);
document.write("<br>");

var Student2 = prompt("Enter the student's name");
document.write(" Student 2: " + Student2);
document.write("<br>");

var Student3 = prompt("Enter the student's name");
document.write(" Student 3: " + Student3);
document.write("<br>");

var Student4 = prompt("Enter the student's name");
document.write(" Student 4: " + Student4);
document.write("<br>");

var Student5 = prompt("Enter the student's name");
document.write(" Student 5: " + Student5);
document.write("<br>");

document.write("<br>");
document.write( "The sorted list:" );

var studentList = ["\n" + Student1, "\n" + Student2, "\n" + Student3, "\n" + Student4, "\n" + Student5];
document.write("<br>");

studentList.sort();
document.write(studentList);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

```
var studentList = [Student1, \n, Student2, \n, Student3, \n, Student4, \n, Student5];

var studentList = [Student1, "\n", Student2, "\n", Student3, "\n", Student4, "\n", Student5];

var studentList = [Student1\n, Student2\n, Student3\n, Student4\n, Student5];

var studentList = [Student1, \n, Student2, \n, Student3, \n, Student4, \n, Student5];
```

I've also tried:

```
document.write(\n + studentList);
document.write("\n" + studentList);
```

The new line is \n from the sources I looked at, I also tried 
 which also didn't work. All the solutions I looked at did not work and any variation of \n I tried either was wrong or broke the prompt. This is the very first assignment in the course so we haven't really covered anything else at all other than if/else and very very basic arrays.

Comment: `[Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4, Student5].join("<br>")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't render newlines. Notice that this markup has newlines but the rendered output doesn't:

```html
student 1
student 2
student 3
student 4
student 5
```

There are a number of ways to get HTML to render line breaks. The simplest is the `<br/>` element.

Appending a `<br/>` to the end of each line gets us the desired breaks:

```html
student 1<br/>
student 2<br/>
student 3<br/>
student 4<br/>
student 5<br/>
```

To accomplish this with your array you could [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the names with a `<br/>`:

```js
const names = [
  'student 1',
  'student 2',
  'student 3',
  'student 4',
  'student 5'
]

const withBreaks = names.join('<br/>');

// withBreaks is "student 1<br/>student 2<br/>student 3<br/>student 4<br/>student 5"
document.write(withBreaks);
```

Comment: You could also add that HTML doesn't usually render new lines apart from when inside a <pre> element.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I'm aware there are numerous ways to render whitespace. I was trying to keep the answer as simple and to the point as possible.